# Why does my unmarshaller wait until it has the following start element to return using XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, stax

I have a Python script and Java test running side-by-side.  They both attempt to do the exact same thing - open a socket, receive a never-ending stream of XML, and parse the XML as it is received.  The Python script is using Expat, while the Java test is using XMLStreamReader and an Unmarshaller.

The Python script is always one step/object ahead of the Java test, e.g. when I have enough XML to unmarshal an object, the Python script immediately does so, while the Java unmarshaller only BEGINS the unmarshalling, and WAITS for the beginning of the next XML start tag to stream in before returning the previously unmarshalled object.  If I receive XML objects 20 seconds apart, without fail the Java unmarshaller will NOT return until the next is received.

1. XML Received
2. Python and Java start unmarshalling
3. Python returns immediately
4. New XML Received
5. Java unmarshaller returns
6. Back to step 2

   XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

   while (reader.hasNext()) {
       // Unmarshal here -- hangs until next XML comes in
   }

The **XMLStreamReader** is com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl

This issue seems to also describe it fairly well: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-419

The 2.1.10 classes referred to in that issue appear to be:

- [UnmarshallerImpl](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.10/jaxb-impl-2.1.10-sources.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl.java?format=ok)
- [StAXStreamConnector](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.10/jaxb-impl-2.1.10-sources.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/StAXStreamConnector.java?format=ok)

Comment: probably has something to do with the order that the events are raised as the XML is parsed by the Java code, As always good advice is to use the source Luke!

Comment: Good point about looking at the source.  I tried that, but for whatever reason the source of the implementation that I have of the unmarshaller is not locally available.  I'll check online for the source.

Comment: You don't say which implementation of Java XMLStreamReader you are using (it's an interface, not a concrete class). Some of the implementations are not very good. The best in my experience is Woodstox.

Comment: I added the XMLStreamReader type to the question.  I also changed the XMLStreamReader to XMLEventReader in my test and now do not experience the problem.  The question still stands--where's the hangup?  Possibly in the connectors' final task of "moving beyond the end tag" (staxStreamReader.next() vs. event=staxEventReader.nextEvent())?

Answer (score 0):

The unmarshaller wants to place the "cursor" to the event **following** the end element event of the portion it has unmarshalled. Therefore, it "hangs" until something gets available. From the API doc:

> This method assumes that the parser is on a START_DOCUMENT or
>   START_ELEMENT event. Unmarshalling will be done from this start event
>   to the corresponding end event. If this method returns successfully,
>   the reader will be pointing at the token right after the end event.

However, any XML event will do: maybe you can do some trick by inserting an XML comment into the stream...